# Tutorial 15 - ExaminingServiceClient(python)

Tags: ros, python, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've gone through the previous tutorials and am now having a problem with running the server.  After entering "rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py" in the commmand line, I'm receiving the following error:

```
...
line 4, in <module>
    from beginner_tutorials.srv import *
ImportError: No module named beginner_tutorials.srv
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10644/tutorial-15---examiningserviceclient(python)/) by [wkr101](https://answers.ros.org/users/858/wkr101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That tutorial assumes that you have completed these tutorials:

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage
```

and

```
 http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv
```

If you have not completed these tutorials the beginner_tutorials package will not exist nor will beginner_tutorials.srv.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-19**:
Also it should read "from beginner_tutorials import *".

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I had the same Problem. Solution for me was, as dornhege already gave a hint to
[http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Using_roscp).

Open CMakeLists.txt in the beginner_tutorial directory (`roscd beginner_tutorials/`) in your favorite text editor. Remove # to uncomment the following line:

```
#rosbuild_genmsg()
```

and

```
#rosbuild_gensrv()
```

After removing the # it worked for me.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [pwo](https://answers.ros.org/users/886/pwo/) with karma: 1 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2